# Cross correlation between time series

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation, chemometrics

I have to measure the cross-correlation between different time series in my dataset.

The dataset contains 9358 instances of hourly averaged responses from an array of 5 metal oxide chemical sensors, plus the temperature in Celsius and the relative humidity (%).
I have several questions:

1. should I leave the time series as they are, or is it more appropriate to aggregate the data, perhaps by taking a daily average?
2. since the sensors have different units of measurement, is it necessary to normalize the data before performing the cross-correlation?
3. are there other things I should consider before applying cross-correlation?

Comment: There may be the issue of "seasonality" within each day; if there is then you might want to consider how you would want it to affect your results.